# Lines inside Array

Tags: matrices, arrays, rules

I want to create a line inside an array (for a matrix), among which what I have created is as shown below. (I used `\usepackage{hhline}` and `\usepackage{arydshln}`)

[image]

```
 \[\small{\left [\begin{array}{cc|c}
 1 & 2 &  3\\ \hhline{-|-|~}
 4 & 6 & 1\\ \hhline{~|~|-}
 -1 & -3 & 0 
\end{array}\right ]},\quad \small{\left [\begin{array}{c|c|c}
1 & 2 & 3 \\ \hhline{-|~|-}
4 & 6 & 1 \\ \hhline{-|~|-}
-1 &-3 & 0
\end{array} \right ]},\quad \small{\left [\begin{array}{c|c|c}
1 & 2 & 3 \\ \hline
4 & 6 & 1 \\ \hhline{-|~|~}
-1 &-3 & 0
\end{array} \right ]},\quad \]
```

But I don't know how to create a matrix with separate vertical lines as shown below. How to create vertical lines in arrays (in math mode `\[...\]`)?

[image]

Comment: you can not use `\small` in math (and it does not have a `{...` argument

Comment: When I tried the resulting font size was smaller than the original, so I guess it worked.

Comment: no, you would have a warning from latex that  it does not work, some constructs will change size, some will not, depending on internal implementation details

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since vertical rules in a regular `tabular` or `array` are governed by the column specification, you can identify the column specification that matches *most* of your layout, and adjust the nuances via `\multicolumn`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\[
  \left(\begin{array}{ c c c | c c }
    1 & 9 & 7 & 0 & 0 \\
    2 & 4 & 5 & 0 & 0 \\
    \hline
    0 & 0 & \multicolumn{1}{| c }{0} & 3 & 3
  \end{array}\right)
\]

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

It may well be an overkill for this very task but `nicematrix` can be used for this and more advanced tasks.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}

\[\begin{pNiceMatrix}
    1  & 9  & 7  & 0  & 0 \\ 
    2 & 4 & 5 & 0 & 0\\
    0 & 0 & 0 & 3 & 3
\CodeAfter
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw (3-|1) -- (3-|6)  (3-|3) -- (4-|3) (3-|4) -- (1-|4);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{pNiceMatrix}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]